# Build QtLocation module for Android

Tags: android, qt, build, location

Nowadays I am trying to build Qt 5.1.2 for Android(for armeabi libs)

I figured out that Qt5 sources from git does not include QtLocation and some other modules.
So I tried

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qtlocation.git qtlocation 
perl init-repository -f
./configure -android-toolchain-version 4.8 -android-arch armeabi -android-ndk-host linux-x86 -developer-build -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk /home/onurozcelik/Android/android-ndk-r9/ -android-sdk /home/onurozcelik/Android/android-sdk-linux/ -skip qttools -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples
make
```

After make got the following error

```
Entering directory `/home/onurozcelik/qt5/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/poly2tri'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `first'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/onurozcelik/qt5/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/poly2tri'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/onurozcelik/qt5/qtlocation/src/3rdparty'
cd location/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/onurozcelik/qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/onurozcelik/qt5/qtlocation/src/location/location.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
Project ERROR: Module does not define version.
make[1]: *** [sub-location-make_first-ordered] Error 3
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/onurozcelik/qt5/qtlocation/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

What is the problem? How can I build QtLocation for Android?

Answer (score 2):

Clone and build Qt Location
`git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qtlocation.git

cd qtlocation

qmake # from qt5

make

make docs

sudo make install`